# Query data in SheetA where column matches SheetB

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets, SheetA and SheetB. The Rows in each sheet are unsorted but there is a 1:1 map of Columns A on each sheet.  I am trying to do something like sql, where i say:
`=select B from SheetA where SheetA.name == SheetB.A2`

```
SHEETA
name, age
foo,   20
gary,  30

--------
SHEETB
name, hobby,  age
gary,  kites, =select B from SheetA where SheetA.name == A2
foo,   boats,  ...
```

I was trying the query but that returns lists, which actually would be what i wanted, but the data is not expected to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like some LOOKUP? You can try with:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet B'!A2:A,'Sheet B'!B2:B ,,0)
```

And, if you want for the whole column'

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(A2:A,'Sheet B'!A2:A,'Sheet B'!B2:B ,,0))
```

Comment: It seems like this isnt working.  It is telling me "Array Arguments to XLOOKUP are of different Size."  When looking at the columns, it all looks correct though.  Trying to better understand what it is looking for.

Comment: That's odd, check that both ranges of Sheet B start and end in the same cells. In my formula `'Sheet B'!A2:A,'Sheet B'!B2:B` If not you can set a VLOOKUP: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP (A2:A,'Sheet B'!A2:B,2,0)))`

Comment: OH, so the results item is the reference to the results, not the destination cell. Got it. It works now